# How to deploy a file system driver?

Tags: windows, deployment, filesystems, driver, minifilter

I was trying to test this [File System Minifilter Driver](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/delete) sample. I'm having a problem with the deployment because this is not an actual device driver (non-PnP driver).

In Visual Studio, in the **property** page of the project: **Driver Install** -> **Deployment**, If I select "Hardware ID Update", I don't know what is the hardware ID for the driver and I cannot see in the .INF file either.

If I select "Install/Reinstall and Verify" -> "Default Driver Package Installation Task (possible reboot)", I get `Driver Deployment Task Failed: Default Driver Package Installation Task` error.

[Deployment settings in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0mAi.png)

I checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/installing-a-file-system-driver) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/installing-a-minifilter-driver) page but I couldn't find anything beside how to prepare the .INF file.

How can I deploy this driver to my target machine? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need an INF file to install your mini filter driver.

First, create a kernel driver service with either "sc create" from command line or call "CreateService" from your installation program if you want to automate the deployment.

Then, add some registry modification as below (from Norton 360) with Registry Editor or again with Win32 registry APIs in your installation program:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SymEFASI\Instances]
"DefaultInstance"="SymEFASI"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SymEFASI\Instances\SymEFASI]
"Flags"=dword:00000000
"Altitude"="260610"
```

Replace "SymEFASI" with your driver service name when running "sc create" or calling "CreateService". The most important part is "Altitude". It needs to be unique in your system, otherwise Filter Manager won't load your driver due to conflicts. For a formal product deployed in the real world to end-users, you need to apply for a unique number assigned by Microsoft. This is also critical because mini filter drivers are classified by layers. Each layer has its own functionalities. If your driver sits on the wrong layer, you might not see the correct data or behavior as you want.

Once the above is done, the last thing is to run "sc start" or call "StartService".

Answer (score 0):

I have a procedure that worked for me.
You need to have a host machine (*where you dev your driver using Visual Studio*) and a target machine (*where you will test your driver. I suggest using a VM to avoid potential crash*).
I suppose you already have developed your driver and you are about to deploy and test it.

1. On your host machine, build your driver using Visual Studio (*Build -> Build project*)
2. In your driver project folder locate the **.cat**/**.inf**/**.sys** files (*x64/Debug/ folder for instance*) and copy these three files
3. In your target machine, paste these three files (*for example in C:\Minifilters<yourDriverName> folder*)
4. Download an place [DbgView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) **inside** the folder where you pasted the **.cat**/**.inf**/**.sys** files on your target machine.
5. If the .cat is not a valid certificate, make it valid.
6. Install the .inf file (*right click -> Install*)
7. Open a console in admin mode and change directory to location of the folder where you pasted the three files.
8. Create the driver using `sc create <yourDriverName> binPath= <full path to driverName.sys> type= kernel start= demand error= normal DisplayName= "<give it a display name>"` in the command prompt.
9. Open DbgView in **admin** mode.
10. Load your driver using `sc start <yourDriverName>` or `fltmc load <yourDriverName>`

If you have correctly configured DbgView, you can now debug your driver.

To stop and delete your driver, you can use the following commands: `sc stop <yourDriverName>` and `sc delete <yourDriverName>`, or simply `fltmc unload <yourDriveName>` to unload it.